# How to use a JWT token as login validation?

Tags: javascript, authentication, jwt

I'm making a login page and I've found that JWT tokens are preferred over sessions but I don't understand what to do with a token.

I send user and password uncrypted with ajax to server and validate the user in a php file which then returns a JWT.

What should I put in my JWT? Do I only check for a token to know if the user is logged in or do I process it somehow to check if it's the right token? If so, how?

So far I've seen examples on client side where you only check if token exists but why should I have hashed data as token instead of a 1 or a 0. I don't get the advantages of this method.

EDIT: Should I both request a JWT token which I store in session storage  and store what the user types in the log in field also in session storage and then compare them with eachother every time the user reloads the page?

Comment: https://jwt.io/introduction/

Comment: I've seen that but I didn't understand why. What should I do with that on client side?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like we need basics of how JWT works here:

1. The client sends username/password to the server using ajax.
2. The server checks username/password and if they are valid, creates an encrypted token, which the only server can read and understand.

   - Server takes into account various fields (also known as "Claims") like "iss" (token issuer) and "Sub" (Subject of token), whole list [here](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token.html#RegisteredClaimName).
   - We can custom fields like user-id which can be used later while validating token.
3. Server sends token back to client through response. Client saves this token in local storage or some variable.
4. With each further request, client sends this token as header.
5. Server examines and validates this token, gets require info from this token like user-id and responds to the user appropriately if valid. Token may also contain expiry date/time, so after a certain time, the server may choose to refuse to serve a client.

[image]

While this may not directly answer your question, it clarifies basic workflow of GWT.

Comment: Oh ok, so what I need to do is ad that token as a header to all my other ajax-requests on the page which requires the user to be logged in and let the server deal with the verification before a respons?

Comment: Exactly. Generally we use header like "Authorization:Bearer 99b82fec-2ec9-4c75-b58d-ef6037d47d93" where that 99b8... is token. If the server responds with 200 (OK), that means our token is valid. If server things token is invalid, it may respond with something like 403: forbidden.

Comment: @user9256633 You may want to accept the answer if you think that's helpful!